# Table without a grid, draw horizontal and vertical grid lines

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, bounding-box

I have the following image:

[image: gridless input image]

> Note, the above image is just an example, I need a solution that will work on every image, my images can be with different sizes, more empty cells or less empty cells, and so on (I'll try to always remove the gridlines before I use the solution I'll find here but still).

I'm trying to draw on it the horizontal and vertical images.

#### Horizontal function:

```py
def getHorizontalCnt(old_image):
  # read image
  img = old_image.copy() # cv2.imread(image_path1)
  hh, ww = img.shape[:2]
  # convert to grayscale 
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  # average gray image to one row
  row = cv2.resize(gray, (1,hh), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
  # threshold on white
  thresh = cv2.threshold(row, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
  plt.imshow(thresh)
  # get contours
  contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
  return contours, ww
```

#### Vertical function:

```py
def getVerticalCnt(old_image):
  # read image
  img = old_image.copy() # cv2.imread(image_path1)
  hh, ww = img.shape[:2]
  # convert to grayscale 
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  # average gray image to one column
  column = cv2.resize(gray, (ww, 1), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
  # threshold on white
  thresh = cv2.threshold(column, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
  # get contours
  contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
  return contours, hh
```

#### Applying them:

```py
original_image = cv2.imread(image_path)
# Horizontal lines
contours_h, ww_ = getHorizontalCnt(original_image.copy())
# Vertical lines
contours_v, hh_ = getVerticalCnt(original_image.copy()) 
# Draw horizontal
for cntr in contours_h:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    ycenter = y + h //2
    cv2.line(original_image, (0, ycenter), (ww_ - 1, ycenter), (0, 0, 0), 1)
# Draw vertical
for cntr in contours_v:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    xcenter = x + w // 2
    cv2.line(original_image, (xcenter, 0), (xcenter, hh_ - 1), (0, 0, 0), 1)
    
plt.imshow(original_image)
```

Result: [image: wrong gridded table]

If I change in the `# Draw horizontal` area from `ycenter = y + h //2` to `ycenter = y + h + 2` I get the following result:

[image: only horizontal seem ok]

In both functions, I tried thresholds from 240 to 255 by raising and lowering 1 by 1 each time, but none worked for me (sometimes I got a different result but still not a good one, the above are the best results I got so far).

#### Update, extra background images:

Input: [image: input extra]

Output: [image: output extra]

### Update input image without `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`

[image: raw image outside of python]

Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR1SV.jpg

Comment: Why not create a new table instead of adding grid lines to images using a script?

Comment: @shounakshastri I need an image with visible gridlines in order to feed it for my model later, what do you mean by creating a new table?

Comment: You did not remove the top, bottom, right, and left black lines first

Comment: @fmw42 Yes i did, just to be clear even more, I added an update of the images with extra background

Comment: I don't see any code to remove those black lines. Please show the code and image after removing the black lines. Then find the lines in that image and add them either to that image or to the original.

Comment: @fmw42 have you looked at the update? I added extra background, I do not see any lines there :(  what I show is the result of `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()` the image inside of it

Comment: Your input table has black lines along the scales which are inside the actual bounds of the image. I have added red lines to real outside of your image to show you still have black lines inside the bounds. Those black lines need to be remove just like any other horizontal and vertical lines in the table.  See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/table4_border_red.png

Comment: The red lines you marked are part of the `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` border, not the image, I'll add the image without the `matplotlib` so you'll see now.

Comment: @fmw42 added the raw

Comment: Please post a link to your original raw image. What you posted is very noisy. So if I threshold at 254 it shows all the noise as black. I do not know if that is real or a product of your capturing and uploading that image. If it is real and not zoomed, then you must find a way to reduce the noise. Otherwise, try different thresholds and look at the thresholded image. Keep trying different ones until you get a clean image without noise.  I tested and it looks like it get clear at about threshold = 230.  But test other values below that. It is always a good idea to look at your threshold result.

Comment: Be sure to look at your threshold image as you change the threshold values. Get a threshold that makes the white clean removing the noise that gets turned black at high threshold values. This is likely because the input image might have originally been a JPG or scanned from a not-pure white background. Once you have lowered the threshold to a value that gives a clean white background, the code should work.  If you have removed all the black lines, then a threshold value that is higher than your black text should be fine. So you can likely go to a lower threshold than 230.

Comment: Always best when debugging, to look at each step of the processing to be sure the result of that step is what you expect for what you are doing.

Comment: @fmw42 I added a link to the original photo,maybe there is noise but I'm not sure how to handle it :(

Comment: @fmw42 I tried lowering to 230, 255 threshold but still, not good solution at all :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252086/discussion-between-fmw42-and-dolev-miz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following draws your lines on your table in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- threshold (at 220, but may be image dependent) to remove the noise in your image. Note you won't see the noise unless you threshold at a high value)
- Average the threshold image to one row
- Threshold that at 254
- Apply a small horizontal morphology open to connect the period in the 5th text column header so no extra line is drawn there.
- Get the contours and bounding box and the X centers.
- Draw contours as vertical lines at the X coordinates on a copy of the input for the vertical lines result and on a second copy of the input (for the final result)
- Average the threshold to one column
- Threshold that at 254
- Get the contours and bounding box and the Y centers.
- Draw contours as horizontal lines at the Y coordinates on a copy of the input for the horizontal lines result and on the previous second copy of the input (for the final result)
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('table4b.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold on white
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# average gray image to one row
row = cv2.resize(thresh, (ww, 1), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# threshold on white
thresh1 = cv2.threshold(row, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply small amount of morphology to merge period with column of text
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (5,1))
thresh1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# get contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
result = img.copy()
result1 = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    xcenter = x + w // 2
    cv2.line(result1, (xcenter,0), (xcenter, hh-1), (0, 0, 0), 1)
    cv2.line(result, (xcenter,0), (xcenter, hh-1), (0, 0, 0), 1)

# average gray image to one column
column = cv2.resize(thresh, (1, hh), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# threshold on white
thresh2 = cv2.threshold(column, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
# get contours

contours = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
result2 = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    ycenter = y + h // 2
    cv2.line(result2, (0, ycenter), (ww-1, ycenter), (0, 0, 0), 1)
    cv2.line(result, (0, ycenter), (ww-1, ycenter), (0, 0, 0), 1)
    
# save results
cv2.imwrite('table4_threshold.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('table4_column_lines.png', result1)
cv2.imwrite('table4_row_lines.png', result2)
cv2.imwrite('table4_column_and_row_lines.png', result)
   
# show result
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result1', result1)
cv2.imshow('result2', result2)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Row Lines Image:

[image]

Column Lines Image:

[image]

Row and Column Lines Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried, but some threshold may be needed to adjusted for input image...

(The code is C++, but I think you can read what it's doing from the comments.)

```cpp
int main()
{
    //- Load Image as GrayScale
    cv::Mat Img = cv::imread( "Tbl.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
    if( Img.empty() ){  std::cout << "imread() failed" << std::endl;    return 0;   }

    //- Count white pixels for each row
    std::vector<int> WhitePixCnts( Img.rows, 0 );
    {
        const unsigned char PixValThresh = 200; //Threshold 1
        for( int y=0; y<Img.rows; ++y )
        {
            const unsigned char *p = Img.ptr<unsigned char>( y );
            for( int x=0; x<Img.cols; ++x, ++p )
            {
                if( *p >= PixValThresh ){   ++WhitePixCnts[y];  }
            }
        }
    }

    //- Grouping consecutive white rows
    std::vector< std::pair<int,int> > WhiteBelts;
    {
        const int CntThresh = (int)( Img.cols * 0.95 ); //Threshold 2

        int BeltTopY = -1;
        for( int y=0; y<Img.rows; ++y )
        {
            if( WhitePixCnts[y] < CntThresh )
            {
                if( BeltTopY >= 0 )
                {
                    WhiteBelts.emplace_back( BeltTopY, y );
                    BeltTopY = -1;
                }
            }
            else if( BeltTopY<0 ){  BeltTopY = y;   }
        }
        if( BeltTopY >= 0 )WhiteBelts.emplace_back( BeltTopY, Img.rows );
    }

    //* (For simplification)
    //  In this sample, if the number of groups is insufficient here, give up.
    if( WhiteBelts.size() < 3 ){    std::cout << "give up" << std::endl;    return 0;   }

    //- Decide the threshold for belt thickness based on the found belt's thickness
    int ThicknessThresh = 0;
    {
        int MaxBeltThickness = 0;

        for( int i=1; i+1<WhiteBelts.size(); ++i ) //* Excluding top and bottom belt, because they will include margin.
        {
            const auto &Belt = WhiteBelts[i];
            MaxBeltThickness = std::max( MaxBeltThickness, Belt.second - Belt.first );
        }
        //Very simple decision...
        ThicknessThresh = (int)( MaxBeltThickness * 0.5 );  //Threshold 3
    }

    //- Accept top, bottom, and enoughly bold belts
    cv::Mat ShowImg;
    cv::cvtColor( Img, ShowImg, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR );
    
    for( int i=0; i<(int)WhiteBelts.size(); ++i )
    {
        const auto &Belt = WhiteBelts[i];
        if( i==0  ||  (i+1)==(int)WhiteBelts.size()  ||  ( Belt.second - Belt.first >= ThicknessThresh ) )
        {
            int BeltCenterY = ( Belt.first + Belt.second ) / 2;
            cv::line( ShowImg, cv::Point(0,BeltCenterY), cv::Point(ShowImg.cols,BeltCenterY), cv::Scalar(0,0,255) );
        }
    }
    cv::imshow( "Result", ShowImg );
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

This is result:
[image]

And this result is obtained from 90 degree rotated input image:
[image]

(The complete result is obtained simply by combining these.)